# Can't set 2d string array in function in C

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to understand string, array and pointers in C. I wrote the below code to exercise but couldn't get the expected result. Can you help me to show where is the problem?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

int main(void) {

    uint8_t *strArr[3][100];

    func1(100, strArr);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", *strArr[i]);
    }
}

void func1(uint8_t col, uint8_t *arr[][col]) {

    uint8_t ix = 0;
    uint8_t *pt[100];

    for (ix = 0; ix < col; ix++) {

        func2(pt);

        *arr[ix] = *pt;

        ix++;
    }
}

void func2(uint8_t **str) {

    static uint8_t a = 0;

    uint8_t msg[100] = "HelloWorld";
    uint8_t msg2[100] = "HelloMars";
    uint8_t msg3[100] = "HelloJupi";

    if (a == 0)
        *str = msg;
    else if (a == 1)
        *str = msg2;
    else
        *str = msg3;

    a++;
}
```

Right now my code compiled without error or warning but gives no output. I was expecting an output like this:

```
HelloWorld
HelloMars
HelloJupi
```

Comment: Arguments are passed by value in C. That includes pointers. That includes pointers to arrays of 3 of arrays of 100 `uint8_t` elements. `*arr[ix]` doesn't do what you think it does, it does `*(arr[ix])` - `arr` doesn't point anywhere, and `arr[ix]` is a way of out of bound access. All `msg` `msg2` `msg3` variables have auto storage duration - they stop existing when `func2` function ends, the pointer `*str` becomes invalid when the function exits. And because pointers are passed by value, the `*pt[100]` pointers in func1 is not updated.

Comment: There are so many problems with the code as it is, that there isn't one place to show where the problem is. I believe a good and long read about pointers, functions, function arguments, about for how long variables are valid, ie. storage durations, and about pointers to arrays could clear things up. Please show what is the "expected result"? Please show what are you getting from the code presented? And please add relevant `#include`s to the code.

Comment: A little too many `ix++`

Comment: `uint8_t *pt[100];` is an array with 100 uint8_t pointers - sure that is what you want?

Comment: Why use `uint8_t` for strings? Use `char`

Comment: `*str = msg;` is saving the value of a local variable. Don't do that...

Comment: Please note that `char` is a signed type in many systems.

Comment: I was expecting an output as like this: HelloWorld HelloMars HelloJupi